# Trying to set up global object, but getting NameError object is not defined when trying to access subclass from another file

Tags: python, object, tkinter, global

I'm trying to understand how Python classes work to be able to follow the four pillars of OOP.

I'm trying to set up a Controller class that will set up some UI classes and respond to input. Currently the Controller class inits a frame which inits some Buttons. The controller passes a click(x,y) function to the UI classes to listen to clicks. That part is currently working, but I can't seem to figure out how the controller class can access it's subclass to do changes to the UI.

Here's the code I got so far. My problem is that the Click(x,y) function in Controller cannot seem to find the "game" object created in **main**.

Controller.py:

```
from GameFrame import GameFrame
global game

def click(x, y):
    global game
    print("%s %s" %(x,y))
    game.changeColor(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global game
    game = GameFrame("title", click) 
    pass
```

GameFrame.py:

```
from GameButtons import GameButtons
from tkinter import *
class GameFrame(object):
    global gameButtons

    def __init__(self, params, click):
        frame = Tk()
        gameButtons= GameButtons(frame,click)
        frame.mainloop()        

    def changeColor(self, x, y):
        gameButtons.buttons[x][y].configure(bg = "green")
```

GameButtons.py:

```
from tkinter import *
class GameButtons(object):

    global buttons
    buttons = [[0 for x in range(8)]for x in range(8)]

    def __init__(self, frame, click):
        for x in range(8):
            for y in range(8):
                b = Button(frame, text = " x ", command = lambda row = x, col = y: click(row, col)) 
                b.grid(row = x, column = y)
                global buttons
                buttons[x][y] = b
```

Clicking a button correctly outputs the row/column from the click(x,y) function but then gives me a NameError: name 'game' is not defined when trying to run game.changeColor(x,y)

Would greatly appreciate any help to fix this, or any explanation why what I'm trying to achieve is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error message? Considering `changeColor` never even refers to the `game` object, it's surprising to me that it would appear in a NameError in that context. Are you sure it wasn't `gameButtons`?

Comment: Yes, it is the "game" that triggers the error, not "gamebuttons"
The error occurs when trying to run last line of click(x,y) in Controller class. game.changeColor(x, y) is where it cannot find "game". Of course, since it doesn't find "game" it won't find gamebuttons either, but the error breaks the call before it ever looks for the gamebuttons. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: I'm still a little fuzzy on the details. When I run your code, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'GameButtons'`. If I change the name of the `Buts` class to `GameButtons`, I get `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. Can you check to confirm that the code you're running is identical to the code that appears in this question?

Comment: Syntax issues aside, at the moment `game` can't be accessed from any context, because `game = ...` doesn't actually assign anything to `game` until `GameFrame` finishes executing. But GameFrame doesn't finish executing until `frame.mainloop` finishes executing. But `mainloop` doesn't finish executing until the user closes the window. At which point the program ends. As a rule of thumb, it's usually a good idea to only call mainloop at the top level of your program, exactly to avoid problems like this one.

Comment: @Kevin sorry, I had copied an error when defining buttons[][]. I fixed the code now to be identical to what I am running (buttons = [[0 for x in range(8)]for x in range(8)] )

Comment: @Kevin that explains a lot. I thought game = GameFrame("title", click) would assign a value to "game" once the GameFrame had been created, not when GameFrame window was closed. I moved the mainloop call to a separate function and changed a few things in GameButton class and now it's working and I understand what I did wrong :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never give `GameFrame` a chance to finish initialization, because `mainloop` will not return until the window has been destroyed. Thus, since initialization never finishes, `game` is not properly initialized.

The simple fix is to move the call to `mainloop` outside of the initialization function so that the object can be properly initialized. Your main code should look something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = GameFrame("title", click)
    game.start()
```

Then, you need to define a `start` method in `GameFrame`. This will require that  you hold a reference to the root window. I would write it like this:

```
class GameFrame(object):
    def __init__(self, params, click):
        self.root = Tk()
        gameButtons = GameButtons(self.root, click)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
```

Note: if your goal is true object orientation, you need to remove the dependencies on global variables.

Here's your code rewritten so that it doesn't use global variables, except for `game` which is is global by its very nature:

```
from tkinter import *

class GameButtons(object):
    def __init__(self, frame, click):
        self.buttons = [[None for x in range(8)] for x in range(8)]
        for x in range(8):
            for y in range(8):
                b = Button(frame, text = " x ", command = lambda row = x, col = y: click(row, col)) 
                self.buttons[x][y] = b
                b.grid(row = x, column = y)

class GameFrame(object):
    def __init__(self, params, click):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.gameButtons= GameButtons(self.root,click)

    def changeColor(self, x, y):
        self.gameButtons.buttons[x][y].configure(bg = "green")

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

def click(x, y):
    print("%s %s" %(x,y))
    game.changeColor(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = GameFrame("title", click) 
    game.start()
```

Comment: Thank you. That answer also cleared up some of my confusion about the use of "self".